# An issue with Pagination in Laravel after using simplePaginate()

Tags: laravel

I am getting this error
(2/2) ErrorException A non well formed numeric value encountered
Could anyone who worked with laravel pagination give a hint on how to resolve this problem? Thank you.

```
$crypto_news = CryptoNews::where('status', '=', 1) 
->where('urlToImage', '!=', 'no_preview.png') 
->where('urlToImage', '!=', '') 
->where('lang', 'en')
->where('id', '!=', $id) 
->orderBy('publishedAt', 'desc')->simplePaginate($limit);
```

Comment: Are `$id` and `$limit` set?

Comment: use `paginate($limit)` replaced of `simplePaginate($limit)`

Comment: yes they are set  public function news($id, $alias)

{
    $crypto_news = CryptoNews::where('id', $id)->first();
    if(isset($crypto_news->title)) {
        $data = [
            'crypto_news' => $crypto_news,
            'crypto_related_news' => $this->getRelatedNews($id,100),
            'crypto_most_read_news' => $this->getMostReadNews($id, 7, 6),
            'crypto_news_from_bitcoin' => $this->getNewsFromBitcoin($id, 9)
        ];
        return view(getCurrentTemplate() . '.pages.single_news', $data);
    }
    return redirect('/crypto-coins-news-headlines');
}

Comment: try covering ` $id` and `$limit` with `intval()`.. eg: `->where('id', '!=', intval($id)) `

Comment: still the same error A non well formed numeric value encountered

Answer (score 0):

Use `paginate($limit)` Instated of `simplePaginate($limit)`
and use `{{ $crypto_news->links() }}` in your view.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination

Or

it seems like `$id` or `$limit` is not an integer.

Comment: I get the same error A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: print $id and $limit before running the query to check whether is there any blank space that causes the problem?

Comment: How can i fix this issue  public function news($id, $alias)
 {
  $crypto_news = CryptoNews::where('id', $id)->first();
  if(isset($crypto_news->title)) {
   $data = [
    'crypto_news' => $crypto_news,
    'crypto_related_news' => $this->getRelatedNews($id,100),
    'crypto_most_read_news' => $this->getMostReadNews($id, 7, 6),
    'crypto_news_from_bitcoin' => $this->getNewsFromBitcoin($id, 9)
   ];
   return view(getCurrentTemplate() . '.pages.single_news', $data);
  }
  return redirect('/crypto-coins-news-headlines');
 }

Comment: it works when i use public function getRelatedNews($id, $limit)
 {
      $crypto_news = CryptoNews::take($limit)
   ->where('status', '=', 1)
   ->where('urlToImage', '!=', 'no_preview.png')
   ->where('urlToImage', '!=', '')
   ->where('lang', 'en')->where('id', '!=', $id)
   ->orderBy('publishedAt', 'desc')->get()->toArray(); 
   }

Comment: instead of isset() function use !empty() function.
and print_r($crypto_news); before if statement to check all data is there or not.

Comment: App\CryptoNews Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => alias [2] => author [3] => description [4] => url [5] => urlToImage [6] => publishedAt [7] => lang etc............ and the error  A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: please check $id and $limit first. are those giving you proper values?

Comment: yes they are and it works fine when i use  public function getRelatedNews($id, $limit)
 {
      $crypto_news = CryptoNews::take($limit)
   ->where('status', '=', 1)
   ->where('urlToImage', '!=', 'no_preview.png')
   ->where('urlToImage', '!=', '')
   ->where('lang', 'en')->where('id', '!=', $id)
   ->orderBy('publishedAt', 'desc')->get()->toArray(); }

Comment: public function news($id, $alias)
 {
  $crypto_news = CryptoNews::where('id', $id)->first();
     if(isset($crypto_news->title)) {
   $data = [
    'crypto_news' => $crypto_news,
    'crypto_related_news' => $this->getRelatedNews($id,100),
    'crypto_most_read_news' => $this->getMostReadNews($id, 7, 6),
    'crypto_news_from_bitcoin' => $this->getNewsFromBitcoin($id, 9)
   ];
   return view(getCurrentTemplate() . '.pages.single_news', $data);
  }

  return redirect('/crypto-coins-news-headlines');
 }